# Como usar archivo App.config cuando cambio a producción

Tags: c#, sql, .net, windows-forms

**Buenas noches querida comunidad**
nuevamente trayendo mi problema luego de no poder darle solución.
al grano:
hice una pequeña aplicacion con un solo formulario windows forms
tiene su cadena de conexion a la base de datos y una tabla de ejemplo, en desarrollo funciona correctamente.
pero cuando ya la llevo a una maquina virtual con windows 10 y sql server 2019 no funciona aun cambiando el nombre del servidor. paso a mostrarles todo el código que he creado para que me ayuden a dar con el error:
Les comento que hice la publicación de la aplicación con onceClik, ahora les muestro el código completo.
Es un proyecto en tres capas
capa datos
el archivo de configuración xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="CapaPresentacion.Properties.Settings.cadenaConexion"
            connectionString="Data Source=PC-0001;Initial Catalog=EjemploConexion;Integrated Security=True;"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Clase de conexixón

```
    public class BD_Conexion
{
    public SqlConnection conexion;
    public BD_Conexion()
    {
        var cadenaConexion = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CapaPresentacion.Properties.Settings.cadenaConexion"].ConnectionString;
        conexion = new SqlConnection(cadenaConexion);
    }

    public SqlConnection AbrirConexion()
    {
        if (conexion.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            try
            {

                conexion.Open();
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return conexion;
    }

}
```

la clase para cargar los datos de productos

```
    public class BD_Productos
{
    public DataTable ListaProductos()
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection conexion = new BD_Conexion().AbrirConexion())
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SP_ListarProductos", conexion))
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
                {
                    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                    adapter.Fill(dataTable);
                    return dataTable;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error al obtener la lista de productos: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

ahora tambien tengo la cadena de conexión en las propiedades de la aplicación
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahora cuando publico la aplicación me genera los archivos siguientes
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

dentro de la carpeta me genera los siguientes archivos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

muy bien cuando instalo la aplicación, dentro de la carpeta programas, donde están todos los programas se crea solo un archivo con el nombre de la aplicación.
tengo entendido que deberían tambien crear los demás archivos de configuración, sin la extensión .deploy
por ejemplo de este archivo de configuración
CapaPresentacion.exe.config.deploy
pero no se crea.
ahora yo en este archivo
CapaPresentacion.exe.config.deploy, cambio el nombre del servidor para que apunte al nuevo servidor, pero me muestra erroes uno de ellos es que no se pudo inicializar la cadena de conexión.
les comento también que cuando lo instalo en el equipo que cree la aplicación corre sin problemas.
por favor donde puede o está mi error. por favor ayudenme a resolverlo.

Muchas gracias.
Buenas noches.

Comment: Como que te genera un solo archivo? y el resto? no estan las DLL ni nada??? Lo raro es que estas diciendo que en tu PC anda, entonces si va el archivo de configuracion. Y otra cosa, la configuracion la deberia modificar el usuario despues de instalar, no vos tocando el instalador. Si no, por lo que estas diciendo, es para todos los usuario igual, y entonces bastaria con que agregues un archivo de configuracion estatico.

Comment: gbianchi, gracias por responder, los archivos que he mostrado en las imágenes son todos los archivos que se generan, si hay más, por favor indícame como se debe hacer, por otro lado he leído qué luego de instalar la aplicación, el archivo  .config.deploy se vuelve solo..config, pero en el directorio donde se instala la aplicación solamente aparece el nombre de la aplicación no encuentro conde se guarda el archivo. .config para poderlo cambiar. Yo también soy el usuario. Por favor indícame que más debo verificar y lo haré. Muchas gracias por tu apoyo

Comment: "donde se instala la aplicación solamente aparece el nombre de la aplicación " no entiendo esto.. en el directorio donde se instala, debe estar el exe y todos los otros archivos. Para mi, estas mirando la carpeta equivocada...

Comment: Lo mismo pienso , pero solo está el ejecutable, abre el formulario de la aplicación pero no se conecta con la base de datos, incluso publiqué la aplicación con el nombre del servidor de destino para probar pero no para nada no funciona. Y como me percato que es la carpeta donde se instaló, le doy botón derecho abrir ubicación y me lleva al directorio

Comment: u no estan las dll?? solo el exe?? seguro????

Comment: Efectivamente no están, que podrá pasar gbianchi, hasta si fuera el caso puedo hacer un video para demostrar todo el procedimiento que hago o acceso a mi equipo, pero me gustaría que me ayuden a resolverlo por favor

Comment: No se.. si estas instalando, debe instalar todo. No solo el ejecutable, porque todos los otros arhicvos tambien los necestia. mas que el video, comproba que estas ejecutando donde pensas que se ejecuta. Agrega por ejemplo un mensaje al arrancar tu ejecutable que especifique en que ruta esta.. para mi, lo estas buscando en el lugar equivocado...

Comment: Ok gbianchi voy a revisar nuevamente te lo haré saber

Comment: Por favor me puedes indicar como hago eso del mensaje de inicio?

Comment: no entiendo a que te referis.. mostra de alguna forma la carpeta donde se esta ejecutando...